# Python: Module not found error but package is installed

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import pwntools module on line 2

```
from Crypto.Util.number import *
import pwntools

textstring = 'label'

ascii = [ord(c) for c in textstring]

xor_ascii = [xor(num) for num in ascii]

xor_text = [chr(x) for x in xor_ascii]

print(f'crypto{"".join(xor_text)}')
```

but I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/to/file/file.py", line 2, in 
import pwntools
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwntools'

Here are the steps of what I did:

1. create virtual env
2. pip install pwntools
3. check pip list to confirm module installed
4. write file.py in VSCode
5. make sure venv python interpreter is selected
6. run code and get error

Here are other things I tried

1. global pip install pwntools
2. uninstall and reinstall pwntools (both global and venv)
3. reload windows in VSCode
4. restarted computer
5. pip install other random modules and importing them, it works fine
6. checked spelling

I'm out of ideas.. would appreciate if a kind soul could point me in the right direction

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/globals.html), it seems to be suggesting that you should be using `import pwn` instead of `import pwntools`. Some libraries have different pip names to their import names, which can be quite annoying to catch, so make sure to always check the docs if you have an import problem, since chances are this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

it's not `import pwntools`
it's `import pwn`